# Shopify webhooks API is ignoring the format parameter

Tags: shopify, webhooks

We discovered yesterday that when creating a Shopify webhook using the api, the specified webhook format is being ignored.

For example:

```
>>> hook = shopify.Webhook()
>>> hook.topic = 'products/update'
>>> hook.address = '<REDACTED>'
>>> hook.format = 'json'
>>> hook.save()
True
>>> shopify.Webhook.find()
[webhook(2302062)]
>>> shopify.Webhook.get(2302062)
{'format': 'xml', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 29, 12, 30, 55, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 29, 12, 30, 55, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'topic': 'products/update', 'address': '<REDACTED>', 'id': 2302062}
```

In the example above we try to set the webhook format to 'json', but the webhook is created with a format of 'xml'

This has previously been working. Yesterday was the first occurrence we've seen of this problem.

Webhooks created through the web admin interface still correctly allow the format to be specified as json, however the web admin interface doesn't show any webhooks created through the api, nor vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in shopify_python_api where format was being set on the class rather than on the resource attribute.  I have just fixed this and released shopify_python_api in version 1.0.3, so the problem should go away after upgrading.

Comment: Thanks Dylan - the 1.0.3 update has fixed the issue. Was the format default changed from json to xml at the Shopify end? I'm curious as to how this was previously working correctly. 

Do you have any comment as to why the web admin interface isn't showing any webhooks created through the api, or vice-versa?

Comment: I'm not sure off-hand why this previously worked, just that the format attribute wasn't being sent in the request. Webhooks have ownership so each app can only see their own webhooks, and they can be uninstalled when uninstalling the app.  For an app they are an implementation detail, and merchants should just uninstall the app rather than the webhook.